Implement unique enrollment mechanism between endpoints and remote server
I'd like to design an enrollment mechanism between Win/Linux/MacOS endpoint and a remote server with the following characteristics :

enrollment should be seamless with no user intervention.

well protection to impersonation attacks (enroll as another machine).

Avoid redundant enrollments in the servers for inactive/uninstalled machines.

The main problem here is that the server have no means to trigger connection to the agent in order to get status, so it cannot clean unused UUIDs.
also, the server cannot differentiate between new agents and re-installed agents.


Agent use unique UID provided by the remote server, to be used any for any future POST request.


I've been thinking about 2 approaches.

works similar to DHCP. The agent will save the UUID it got from the server, even after the product is uninstalled (in registry or some other file), so when the product will be re-installed, the agent can use this value and send it to the server upon enrollment, so that the server will hopefully set this value as the agent's UUID.
The drawback here is that while the product is uninstall, I cannot guarantee this value will be properly secured and malicious action can still it and impersonate from this or different machines.

calculate unique value per machine and hash it (like for example take the combination of machine_id + network interface Mac address and hash them - this will ensure uniqueness) so that on every enrollment, the agent suggest the server the same number and we won't have to save it anywhere as it's going to be calculated over again - and it's guaranteed to be the same, so we may reuse UUID and avoid dead agents.
The problem here is that some Windows machines or Virtual machines may be duplicates of one another, so in this case we're going to have a collision.


I wonder if anybody else where looking into similar problem in the past and may advise me for a different approach, it seems that no solution comply with all my goals, so I'm looking for the best one.
Thanks !
